# twentytwenty js | positioning of an <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twentytwenty

I'm working on a Website and there is a case of a "before-after" animation which i did with twentytwenty js.

It works fine everywhere except for one page, where the after image(right side) doesn't seem to fit into the "container". The images should have a light border but it just shows up at the top. Using "border: 1px solid lightgrey" has the same result.

Link to the problem page:

http://www.nordglueck.com/printness/html/Referenz/raumplus_Faltposterbroschuere_Illustration_nach_Bild.html

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what you are expecting?  It's kind of hard to tell exactly what's going on and what you are trying to accomplish.  Maybe show what the solution should look like and what you are getting just in case other browsers aren't showing the same thing as what you're getting.

Comment: I'm getting this:

http://www.nordglueck.com/printness/Bildschirmfoto%202016-06-04%20um%2013.56.33.png

and expecting something like this:

http://www.nordglueck.com/printness/border-closed.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast solution! add `right: 0;` to the `.twentytwenty-container img` in the `twentytwenty.css` file and in your `style.css` file take `2px` from the width and height in the `.bild-1` class

you final output will look like this

**in your twentytwenty.css**

```
.twentytwenty-container img
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    display: block;
```

**in you style.css**

```
.bild-1
    width: 388px;
    height: 348px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
```

Comment: thank you very much! i also found a problem in the html, where i put a "style:border 1px lightgrey" into the containing div...

Comment: I thought that was on purpose! anyway glad you solved the problem @CodingPanda